# Multivariate Gaussian Problem

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The problem is like this:

Conditional on $M=m, Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ is a random sample from the $N(m,\sigma^2)$ distribution. Find the unconditional joint distribution of $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ when $M$ has the $N(\mu, \tau^2)$ distribution. Use induction to show that the covariance matrix $\Omega$ has determinant $\sigma^{2n-2}(\sigma^2+n\tau^2)$, and show that $\Omega^{-1}$ has the diagonal elements $\{\sigma^2+((n-1)\tau^2) / \{ \sigma^2(\sigma^2+n\tau^2)\}  \}$ and off-diagonal elements $-\tau/\{\sigma^2(\sigma^2+n\tau^2)\}$.

Here is what I have done:

$f(y_1,y_2, ..., y_n)\\
 = \int f(y_1,y_2, ..., y_n|m)g(m) dm\\
 = \int \prod_i f(y_i|m) g(m)dm\\
 = \int \{ \prod_i \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{(y_i-m)^2}{2\sigma^2})\} \cdot \frac{1}{\tau\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{(m-\mu)^2}{2\tau^2}) dm$

I don't know how to do the integration. Also, for the rest of the problem I don't have any idea. Please help me.